# How to encrypt in linux using an xml public key

Tags: c#, .net, xml, openssl, public-key-encryption

I created a key pair in `C#` and i'd like to upload the public key to a server so the server can send private data to the client. The server must use this public key, but it's in **XML format**. I've been reading and it seems the best way to encrypt a file in linux using a public key is with `openssl`.

This is how my public key looks like after being generated with `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in `.net`

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>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</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

The fact is that `openssl` only accepts **PEM** (as far as I've seen). *How do I convert this key into something `openssl` can use to encrypt?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it's in XML format

The presentation format is RFC 3275, [XML-Signature Syntax and Processing](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3275.txt).

---

> How do I convert this key into something openssl can use to encrypt?

You will need to parse the RFC 3275 `RSAKeyValue`, then put it in an OpenSSL `RSA` structure.

Its somewhat painful.... are you sure you want to see it? (The XML parsing is left as an exercise to the reader, but it uses the values you provided above).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ret = -1;

    char nz[] = "sqprMX0n4y1gmmgpTt6pHb870k5U0MIuXixidD+S8foQf5Bb"
             "FS44kth2uWDKzXOXqiONxIPHPb+84XdxrRi2O7bvLysztgrF"
             "eU8oNDMeuIwJOKVQzKoJ1vGqjBKiA9w48oQKxvO+Ck3GmObW"
             "67LFNcrt50sEco2/OMmrpiH3W8hRx55TcR1flCJduU0/6jA7"
             "Yct9ZfhOw5wBq6o5IwiT8Mi1R6LVq9sTzSNAWHC/bFcEONkt"
             "z6NgUKbFKtt+mTfFGToiwPB1L4TecGyTIweH84nl8jVAngcM"
             "vvFP415Eg1kd9PJbRqrIESM5AU1YcsapWV3bsqEGVS2y+r5N"
             "4yzXPCYRCRyFWJSnNVlax+gtDFTNz3m9UT8m2E7elGe5hPhR"
             "6nN3votzBNvTeQ4Lwc5JDIvnWUg7aOdVIXnHQbBqEQke79BX"
             "xIv8tzVPczGkFqFExkmPPQQv8zJvBKkIYc+BFJtkylBiZfQX"
             "0590NS3L1y31VSeXn8Ncx2/ceJfUXsMWJ3sQ+dk51MKBJ2LL"
             "oyJq8IgloBLnXWvlYZ+tkzRVTExFR277V3Jr17DeTOMQGEg5"
             "HqRkbDDVGPTl2RvC2S2BTe7+r9xNzyAZMieVjZLZgb6icE6u"
             "SJFcu4qqJ1khQUjW7taymqW8Ao3oEiCUJKvRpZcJPMN+JtMn"
             "ji+2we17ytk=";

    char ez[] = "AQAB";

    BIO* nn = NULL, *ee = NULL;
    BIO* b1 = NULL, *b2 = NULL;
    RSA* rsa = NULL;

    nn = BIO_new_mem_buf(nz, strlen(nz));
    if(!nn) { ret = 1; goto done; }

    ee = BIO_new_mem_buf(ez, strlen(ez));
    if(!ee) { ret = 2; goto done; }

    b1 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if(!b1) { ret = 3; goto done; }

    b2 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if(!b2) { ret = 4; goto done; }

    /* If you leave these out even though you   */
    /* are reading, then BIO_read will return 0 */
    /* and BIO_should_retry will return false   */
    BIO_set_flags(b1, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    BIO_set_flags(b2, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    nn = BIO_push(b1, nn);
    if(!nn) { ret = 5; goto done; }

    ee = BIO_push(b2, ee);
    if(!ee) { ret = 6; goto done; }

    rsa = RSA_new();
    if(rsa == NULL) { ret = 7; goto done; }

    unsigned char buff[4096];
    const int bsize = sizeof(buff);
    int rr = 0, rd = 0;

    /* See http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=123171064303018&w=2 */
    /* for this contorted goodness */
    rd = 0;
    do {
        rr = BIO_read(nn, buff + rd, bsize - rd);
        if(rr < 0) { ret = 8; goto done; } /* failed */

        rd += rr;
    } while (rr > 0 || BIO_should_retry(nn));

    if(rd == 0) { ret = 9; goto done; }

    rsa->n = BN_bin2bn(buff, rd, NULL);
    if(rsa->n == NULL) { ret = 10; goto done; }

    rd = 0;
    do {
        rr = BIO_read(ee, buff + rd, bsize - rd);
        if(rr < 0) { ret = 11; goto done; } /* failed */

        rd += rr;
    } while (rr > 0 || BIO_should_retry(ee));

    if(rd == 0) { ret = 12; goto done; }

    rsa->e = BN_bin2bn(buff, rd, NULL);
    if(rsa->e == NULL) { ret = 13; goto done; }

    /***** Paydirt *****/

    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);

    ret = 0;

done:

    if(ret != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse and validate RSA key\n");

    if(rsa)
       RSA_free(rsa), rsa = NULL;

    if(nn)
        BIO_free_all(nn), nn = NULL;

    if(ee)
        BIO_free_all(ee), ee = NULL;

    return ret;
}
```

---

> How to encrypt in linux using an xml public key

With the `RSA` from above, try `RSA_encrypt` (and `RSA_verify`). See [rsa(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html) in the OpenSSL docs.

---

> The fact is that openssl only accepts PEM (as far as I've seen).

OpenSSL accepts `PEM` and `DER`.

---

Here's the output of the program above on your parameters.

```
$ ./rsa-test.exe
Public-Key: (4096 bit)
Modulus:
    00:b2:aa:6b:31:7d:27:e3:2d:60:9a:68:29:4e:de:
    a9:1d:bf:3b:d2:4e:54:d0:c2:2e:5e:2c:62:74:3f:
    92:f1:fa:10:7f:90:5b:15:2e:38:92:d8:76:b9:60:
    ca:cd:73:97:aa:23:8d:c4:83:c7:3d:bf:bc:e1:77:
    71:ad:18:b6:3b:b6:ef:2f:2b:33:b6:0a:c5:79:4f:
    28:34:33:1e:b8:8c:09:38:a5:50:cc:aa:09:d6:f1:
    aa:8c:12:a2:03:dc:38:f2:84:0a:c6:f3:be:0a:4d:
    c6:98:e6:d6:eb:b2:c5:35:ca:ed:e7:4b:04:72:8d:
    bf:38:c9:ab:a6:21:f7:5b:c8:51:c7:9e:53:71:1d:
    5f:94:22:5d:b9:4d:3f:ea:30:3b:61:cb:7d:65:f8:
    4e:c3:9c:01:ab:aa:39:23:08:93:f0:c8:b5:47:a2:
    d5:ab:db:13:cd:23:40:58:70:bf:6c:57:04:38:d9:
    2d:cf:a3:60:50:a6:c5:2a:db:7e:99:37:c5:19:3a:
    22:c0:f0:75:2f:84:de:70:6c:93:23:07:87:f3:89:
    e5:f2:35:40:9e:07:0c:be:f1:4f:e3:5e:44:83:59:
    1d:f4:f2:5b:46:aa:c8:11:23:39:01:4d:58:72:c6:
    a9:59:5d:db:b2:a1:06:55:2d:b2:fa:be:4d:e3:2c:
    d7:3c:26:11:09:1c:85:58:94:a7:35:59:5a:c7:e8:
    2d:0c:54:cd:cf:79:bd:51:3f:26:d8:4e:de:94:67:
    b9:84:f8:51:ea:73:77:be:8b:73:04:db:d3:79:0e:
    0b:c1:ce:49:0c:8b:e7:59:48:3b:68:e7:55:21:79:
    c7:41:b0:6a:11:09:1e:ef:d0:57:c4:8b:fc:b7:35:
    4f:73:31:a4:16:a1:44:c6:49:8f:3d:04:2f:f3:32:
    6f:04:a9:08:61:cf:81:14:9b:64:ca:50:62:65:f4:
    17:d3:9f:74:35:2d:cb:d7:2d:f5:55:27:97:9f:c3:
    5c:c7:6f:dc:78:97:d4:5e:c3:16:27:7b:10:f9:d9:
    39:d4:c2:81:27:62:cb:a3:22:6a:f0:88:25:a0:12:
    e7:5d:6b:e5:61:9f:ad:93:34:55:4c:4c:45:47:6e:
    fb:57:72:6b:d7:b0:de:4c:e3:10:18:48:39:1e:a4:
    64:6c:30:d5:18:f4:e5:d9:1b:c2:d9:2d:81:4d:ee:
    fe:af:dc:4d:cf:20:19:32:27:95:8d:92:d9:81:be:
    a2:70:4e:ae:48:91:5c:bb:8a:aa:27:59:21:41:48:
    d6:ee:d6:b2:9a:a5:bc:02:8d:e8:12:20:94:24:ab:
    d1:a5:97:09:3c:c3:7e:26:d3:27:8e:2f:b6:c1:ed:
    7b:ca:d9
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

Comment: Actually i ended up using a script on the server side to convert the pub key. But thank you a lot.